# Run two function inside a loop in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, random-number-generator

I have this formula for creating random number `=DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(100,1000),8)` in my excel sheet. But I want to convert it to vba.

After a lot of hassle I came to this :

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (lRow + 1)).Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 5000)
```

But I am able to import only one function like the example. But I have to import both the function `Randbetween` and `DEC2HEX`.

Hope Undestand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You need to use this VBA code:*

```
Sub HEXARandomNumber()
 
Dim randomNumber As Integer
Dim DEC2HEXNUM As Variant

randomNumber = Int(100 + Rnd * (1000 - 2 + 1))
DEC2HEXNUM = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(randomNumber, 8)


Debug.Print randomNumber
Debug.Print DEC2HEXNUM
 
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = randomNumber
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = DEC2HEXNUM

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- *To generate a random number between two values, you have to use combination of the RND & INT Function.*
- *Value 100,1000 and cell range A1, A2 are editable.*

Comment: you didn't get my point bro. I am not interested to change my code. I tried WorksheetFunction.DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(100,1000),8). But it comes an error. Can you solve it in this way?

Comment: @Mehedi,,, read carefully **N.B.** section,, it's clear that how could you achieve,,, the method U are trying DOESN't WORKs,,, !!

Comment: okay bro. thank you.

Comment: Dear bro, your answer is not wrong. But I am searching for another type of solution. I think i am unable to make understand you. No matter. Thanks a lot for being helping me. I am giving my vote to your answer. Be happy :)

Comment: @Mehedi,, this is what U in Wsheet,, `=DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(100,1000),8)` and you want to convert it into VBA and struggling with this `ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (lRow + 1)).Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 5000)`  and I have suggested the correct formula to get RANDOM number using VBA also,,, Decimal to Hexa,,, if U need something different,,, then [edit] your post & be loud and clear about your need !!

Comment: Okay bro. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Mehedi,, glad to help you keep asking ☺

Comment: Bro can you solve this?https://superuser.com/q/1578195/1207783