# macro enabled excel sheet asks to save every time as new sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a macro enabled excel sheet. Whenever I enter from excel recent workbooks and edit the sheet then it is all okay.
But whenever I open it from my file manager and edit the sheet then at the time of exiting it takes me to the `save as` option. It is then no longer my existing file. Excel wants to save this as a new sheet.

Pls help me out to get rid of this disaster!

[image: Excel force me to save as option]

Comment: it's very unusual phenomena,,, I've never experienced,,, we all are doing this many times in a day,, but if possible upload the file on cloud and let me examine!!

Comment: It is harassing me so much. Pls look at this matter. Here is the file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jiclzk1kn7ojdw/Random%20Number%20Generator.xltm?dl=0

Comment: Hi @Mehedi,,, nothing wrong with the file & what you are talking about never happened with me,,,, I've open the file from both ways,,, you just check one thing,,, hit FILE,, OPTION,,,,  SAVE,,,, and find on top is SAVE FILE IN THE FORMAT,, find & set Excel Macro Enable *.xlsm.  then open and SAVE it in same Drive\FOLDER.  Close & reopen U find is now no SAVE As,,,☺

Comment: Dear bro, it helped! Yes, the problem was in the setting. Thanks a lot for the solution and helpful mind.

Comment: You helped me. Why shouldn't I accept your answer?Please post and I will vote it. Thank you again!

Comment: Bro will you check it out? https://superuser.com/q/1578922/1207783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To get rid form the issue, do the following:*

1. Hit the **F**ile TAB.
2. Click **O**ption command.
3. Now from **E**xcel option list, hit **S**ave.
4. On left top find **S**ave files in this formats.
5. From Combo box select, **E**xcel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm).
6. Finish with **O**k.
7. Now, **S**ave the file in Same Drive/Folder (as Macro Enabled Workbook).
8. **C**lose the & Re-open.

*You find now no Save As appears.*

Comment: Hi @Mehedi,, glad to help you keep asking ☺