# if function run when a specific value is entered in a specific cell in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

**Updated Code!**

I want to create a sheet in which if i enter "Hello" in cell `A1` then a row will be inserted automatically.
I tried this code in my vba.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" And Target.Value = "Hello" Then
    Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
End If
End Sub
```

It did the job. If I input Hello in the cell `A1` it inserts a row. But then every time I make change to the worksheet then every time a row is inserted.

I know that this is for the declaration. `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`
It's job that every time I make a change to my worksheet then the code will be run. Then it enter into the if condition and check the condition. Then it finds that Hello is inputed in cell `A1`. So it inserts a row again. How to get rid of this bro?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to add this `If Intersect(Target, Range("$A$1")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` , then test for Hello.

Comment: @mehedi: "Have you tested the same code in your excel sheet?" no, I haven't tested it, this forum is for giving advice not to do others' job.

Comment: Thanks bro. It helped. But one thing, yes this forum is for giving advice not to do others job but if you had tested the code then you wouldn't tell me that you are not understanding why my code is giving error with your solution. Don't mind, take it positive. Thanks a lot for the help and I apologizes if I said anything wrong. Happy coding :)

Comment: @Mehedi ,,, suggestions by community members should  be taken on positive note ,, # Mate Juhasz , advice is simple that, what you are asking must be supported by,, some research,, formula or method you have applied,,, and better upload screen shot,,, if getting any error and nothing more,,, keep asking☺